# how to auto save inputRichText content before validate

Tags: ckeditor, validation, icefaces, fckeditor, icefaces-3

I have some trouble with inputRichText component (icefaces 3)

```
<ice:inputRichText  id="content" value="#{CchcDmFeedbackController.objFeedback.fbContent}"
       required="true" requiredMessage="This is required" skin="office2003" 
       styleClass="editor"  saveOnSubmit="true" toolbar="MyToolbar"
       customConfigPath="#{resource['js:CKConfig.js']}"/>   
<ice:message for="content"/>
```

and my CKConfig.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
   config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';
   config.toolbar_MyToolbar = [['Bold','Italic', 'Underline'], ['Save']];
   config.contentsCss = '/css/CKStyle.css';
};
```

1. This code return javascript error, it seem to be could not find out my toolbar config, my js path is right (I sure)
2. Although using saveOnSubmit="true" first time I submit my form, content is not save, validator catch it content as empty (show validate msg), second times submit form it will pass, I think it validate before save content (instead of save before and validate after then)

Can anyone help me :(

Answer (score 0):

sorry about this post. I think I had miss something in config file, it work fine right now.
my new config file :

```
CKEDITOR.config.resize_maxWidth = "100%";
CKEDITOR.config.tabSpaces = 5;
CKEDITOR.config.defaultLanguage = 'vi';
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
    [
        [ 'Source','-','Save','Preview'],
        [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] ,
        [ 'Find','Replace','SelectAll' ] ,
        '/',                    
        [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','-','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] ,
        [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock' ] ,
        [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ],
        '/',        
        [ 'Format','Font','FontSize' ],
        ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] ,
        [ 'Link','Unlink'] , 
        [ 'Image','Smiley']             
    ];
```

and xhtml

```
<ice:inputRichText  id="noidung" value="#{CchcDmFeedbackController.objFeedback.fbNoidung}" required="true" requiredMessage="Vui lòng nhập nội dung" skin="kama" styleClass="editor" saveOnSubmit="true" toolbar="MyToolbar"  customConfigPath="/resources/js/CKConfig.js"/> 
<h:message for="noidung"/>
```

Note:
I use CK v3.5, in config file cannot use group name, just [] not {[]}
And in xhtml file, customConfigPath must be static url